# How to cast List<T> to be able to call specific method on respective Object?

Tags: java, generics, casting, generic-list

I'm having something in my mind about generic casting for List, but honestly I don't know if it's possible to implement or not.

There is this code snippet in my application

```
public String getObjectACombo() {
   List<ObjectA> listA = theDAO.getObjectA();
   String combo = getCombo(listA, "rootA"); // --> This line
}

public String getObjectBCombo() {
   List<ObjectB> listB = theDAO.getObjectB();
   String combo = getCombo(listA, "rootA"); // --> This line
}
```

Firstly I was coding some routine for the lines mentioned as "--> This line". But the two methods have the exact same algorithm to generate JSON string from List<?> which has been returned from the database. So I am thinking to replace them with a generic method, getCombo(List<T> list, String root). But the thing is I couldn't mange to make it work.

```
public <T> String getCombo(List<T> list, String root) {
   Iterator<T> listItr = list.iterator();

   ...
   while ( listItr.hasNext() ) {
      jsonObj.put(list.get(i).toJson());  // --> The Error line
   }
}
```

The error happens of the "The Error line". Both ObjectA.java and ObjectB.java have the toJson() method in them, but "The method toJson() is undefined for the type T" at the mentioned line.

I tried to cast it with (T) and Class.forName(), but neither of them had worked.

Is there any work around to this problem? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an interface that defines the `toJson()` method, e.g. `Jsonable` :) - and then restrict `T`:

```
public <T extends Jsonable> String getCombo(List<T> list, String root) { 
 ...
}
```

This way the compiler knows that each `T` must inherit from `Jsonable` and thus has the `toJson()` method.

Edit: here's an example of what I mean, using the already existing `Comparable<T>` interface:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean compare(List<T> list, T other) {
  for( T object : list ) {
    if( object.compareTo( other ) == 0 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }    
  return false;
}

compare( new ArrayList<String>(), "foo"); //compiles, since String implements Comparable<String>
compare( new ArrayList<Object>(), null); //doesn't compile, since Object doesn't implement Comparable<Object>
```

Comment: You mean I should create an interface Jsonable and implements my domain object (ObjectA, ...) from that interface?

Comment: @Khosrow yes: `class ObjectA implements Jsonable`, `class ObjectB implements Jsonable` - Note that I didn't come up with a better name for the interface, though. Maybe you have more success :)

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, for your quick and exact response. It's solved.

Comment: `public <T extends Jsonable> String getCombo(List<T> list, String root)` can be written as `public String getCombo(List<? extends Jsonable> list, String root)`. no `T` needed

Comment: @newacct yes in that case it's not needed. The T however, allows at least some basic usage of the type like additional same type parameters or casting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a for each:

```
public <T> String getCombo( List<T> list, String root )
{
    for (T x : list)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```